# путь к файлу DLL на языке C при компиляции

Tags: c, dll

Возникает ошибка при компиляции проекта с динамической библиотекой, расположенной в папке lib. Помогите разобраться, как правильно указать путь. Спасибо.

***lib/sum.c***

```
#include "sum.h"

int f1(int a, int b) {
 return a + b;
}
```

***lib/sum.h***

```
int f1(int, int);
```

Главный файл **main.c** находится в корне папки, в нем указан путь к файлу **sum.h**. Как бы правильно.

***main.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "./lib/sum.h"

int main(void) {
 printf("%d", f1(10, 20));
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Создание динамической библиотеки проходит замечательно. Она появляется в паке **lib**

> gcc -shared ./lib/sum.c -o ./lib/libsum.dll

А вотпри компиляция проекта с динамической библиотекой из папки **lib** возникает ошибка.

> gcc main.c -o abc.exe -L ./lib/libsum.dll

Comment: `-L lib -lsum` конечно пробовали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, ключ `-L` указывает каталог, в котором будет происходить поиск библиотек, а не путь к самой библиотеке. Во-вторых, имя линкуемой библиотеки указывается с помощью ключа `-l`. Во-третьих, в процессе поиска приставка "lib" и расширение ".dll" будут добавлены автоматически. Во-четвёртых, лучше указывать путь к заголовочным файлам компилятору, а не в коде

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sum.h"

int main(void) {
 printf("%d", f1(10, 20));
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Подытоживая

```
gcc -I./lib -L./lib -o abc.exe main.c -lsum
```

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Gornostaev! Файл abc.exe появился, но при запуске вознакает ошибка, в которой говорится, что библиотека не видна.

Comment: Потому что загрузчик операционной системы не знает где её искать. В Windows динамическая библиотека  должна или находиться в одном каталоге с исполняемым файлом, либо в одном из каталогов, включённых в переменную окружения `PATH`.

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Gornostaev! Теперь все понятно! Я делал стратигическую ошибку, пытаяь вызввать библиотеку из папки lib. Спасибо Вам!